# How can I read all files and directory in a device?

Tags: android, file, permissions, directory

Is it possible to develop a Java application that can read all files and directories in the device's memory?

I think it's not possible (for security reasons), but I need another opinion.

Comment: you mean to say List of files and directories?

Comment: Yes a list of ALL files and directories in a device. I think it's not possible but I need another opinion. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

I will take *path* is the device storage.

If you are using [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) or a likewise tool, put the debug point next to:

```
 File[] dir = new File(path).listFiles();
```

And you will see the file/folder hierarchy.

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()

public static ArrayList<String> listFoldersAndFilesFromSDCard(String path) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayListFolders = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        File[] dir = new File(path).listFiles();
        // Here 'dir' will give you a list of folder/files in the hierarchy

        if (null != dir && dir.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
                if (dir[i].isDirectory()) {
                    arrayListFolders.add(new File(dir[i].toString()).getName());
                    // Here you can call recursively this
                    // function for file/folder hierarchy
                }
                else {
                    // Do whatever you want with the files
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayListFolders;
}
```